# Remove duplicate emails (Outlook 2003)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2003, deduplication

Sometimes our POP server has a fit and it re-sends a bunch of e-mail messages again to a particular user and I have to clean up those duplicate messages that ended up in the local outlook store.

Is there a free utility (or a way to do it in outlook 2003 that I am overlooking) that allows to do this.

My searches showed only non-free add-ons.

Comment: How many duplicates the user get? Does he receive the emails twice or more than that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this?  [Outlook Duplicate Items Remover 1.4.4](http://www.vaita.com/odir.asp)

**Note:** This program will not work in office 64 bit.